# Get the route info within the express app in bluemix

Tags: express, routes, ibm-cloud, hostname

I want to be able to get the Bluemix route information in my application? I tried VCAP_APP_HOST but it returned 0.0.0.0

Comment: Why do you need the route of your application? Express only needs to know the port to run. Example below:
var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('listening at:', port);

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `cfenv` package from NPM, which conveniently exposes environment information among other useful things. The `getAppEnv` method will return the information you are looking for. [See documentation here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/node-cfenv).